# Error al abrir y cerrar conexión a BD SQL desde C#

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, base-de-datos

Tengo el siguiente código que crea carpetas desde una base de datos las crea sin ningún problema, ahora necesito crear una función que reciba como parámetros el **path** de la carpeta que se creo y el **ID** de la carpeta que se creo, necesito ejecutar esta función dentro del **WHILE** para que esta función vaya y haga otra consulta para obtener las carpetas hijas y ya que las tenga pues quiero crearlas y hacerlo recursivo etc...

```
        Program test = new Program();
        string ConnectionString = test.GetConnectionString();
        using (var conn = new SqlConnection(ConnectionString))
        {
            using (var cmd = new SqlCommand())
            {
                cmd.Connection = conn;
                cmd.CommandTimeout = 10000;
                cmd.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM Elements WHERE P_Profile_ID = 2  AND E_Parent_ID = 0 ORDER BY E_Name ASC";
                conn.Open();
                using (var reader = cmd.ExecuteReader())
                {
                    while (reader.Read())
                    {

                        try
                        {
                            string path = @"C:\\Mario\\";//Ruta Raiz aquí se debe de colocar la ruta donde se quiere extraer toda la carpeta
                            path += reader["E_Name"];//Se le concatena el nombre de la carpeta en turno
                            if (Directory.Exists(path))
                            {
                                Console.WriteLine("La carpeta ya existe.");
                                Console.ReadKey();
                                return;
                            }
                            DirectoryInfo di = Directory.CreateDirectory(path);
                            Console.WriteLine("La carpeta fue creada exitosamente.", Directory.GetCreationTime(path));
                            test.GetChildrenFolders("sdfgfsdfgg", Convert.ToInt32(reader["E_Element_ID"]));

                        }
                        catch (Exception ex)
                        {
                            Console.WriteLine("Error fatal de la muerte" + ex.ToString());
                            Console.ReadKey();
                        }
                    }
                    Console.ReadKey();
```

Pero el problema viene que cuando llamo a la función `GetChildrenFolders` ya que necesito hacer otra consulta, pero al crear otra conexión me dice que primero debo cerrar la que esta abierta, pero estoy dentro el ciclo **WHILE** si cierro la conexión cuando regresa a leer el siguiente elemento no puede porque la conexión esta cerrada.

```
   public  int GetChildrenFolders(string path, int id_parent)
    {
        string ConnectionString = this.GetConnectionString();
        using(var recursiva = new SqlConnection(ConnectionString))
        {
            using(var cmd = new SqlCommand())
            {
                cmd.Connection = recursiva;
                cmd.CommandTimeout = 10000;
                cmd.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM Elements WHERE P_Profile_ID = 2 AND E_Parent_ID ="+id_parent+"";
                recursiva.Open();
                using (var res = cmd.ExecuteReader())
                {
                    int count = Convert.ToInt32(cmd.ExecuteReader());
                    if(count > 0){
                        Console.WriteLine("Si tengo subcarpetas");
                    }else
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("No tengo subcarpetas");
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        return 0;
    }
```

Entonces mi pregunta sería ¿Cómo puedo hacer las dos consultas sin cerrar la conexión? No se como utilizar la misma conexión para las dos consultas, y mas teniendo en cuenta que la segunda consulta esta en un método.

Gracias

Comment: Antes de leerme toodo el codigo...Por qué no almacenas los resultados de tu primera consulta en un datatable, cierras la conexion y usas un `foreach` en las filas del datatable?

Comment: Si es una opción, pero quería saber si es posible hacer lo que planteo utilizando la misma conexión con consultas diferentes.

Comment: Intenta como te ha dicho AsierVillanueva, pero añadiendo `MultipleActiveResultSets=True` a tu cadena de conexión,aunque yo usaría un datatable...

Comment: @M.Gress De hecho, y por experiencia, con una conexión de la forma en la que lo estás planteando no es posible ya que te va a decir que dicha conexión se encuentra ocupada con el DataReader. Es posible lo que necesitas siempre y cuando **crees instancias de una conexión**, en vez de utilizar una conexión global. *Deberías utilizar la misma conexión*, no comparto.
**EDIT:** Acabo de leer nuevamente tu código y, por lo visto, haces lo que te sugiero. En mi experiencia **si ha funcionado** pero no lo he comprobado con SQLServer, lo he hecho con MySQL.

Comment: @M.Gress Ya lo haces, si no me equivoco, en el código: `using(var recursiva = new SqlConnection(ConnectionString))` que es otra instancia distinta a la llamada `using (var conn = new SqlConnection(ConnectionString))` por ende no debería darte error. ¿Puedes comunicarnos en que linea específica se produce el error?

Comment: @AgustinM. Me lo marca en  **using (var res = cmd.ExecuteReader()** en el método `GetChildrenFolders` me dice **Ya hay un DataReader abierto asociado a este Command, debe cerrarlo primero**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Deberías utilizar la misma conexión. Además de cara al rendimiento te va a penalizar mucho andar abriendo y cerrando conexiones.

Simplemente pásale como parámetro la conexión abierta al método GetChildrenFolders.

Además puedes utilizar DataAdapters para evitar mantener DataReaders abiertos:

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {

        string ConnectionString = "";

        using (var conn = new SqlConnection(ConnectionString))
        {
            conn.Open();
            var cmd = new SqlCommand
            {
                Connection = conn,
                CommandTimeout = 10000,
                CommandText =
                    "SELECT* FROM Elements WHERE P_Profile_ID = 2  AND E_Parent_ID = 0 ORDER BY E_Name ASC"
            };
            var sqlDa = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
            var data = new DataTable();
            sqlDa.Fill(data);
            foreach (DataRow row in data.Rows)
            {
                try
                {
                    string path = @"C:\\Mario\\";
                    //Ruta Raiz aquí se debe de colocar la ruta donde se quiere extraer toda la carpeta
                    path += row["E_Name"]; //Se le concatena el nombre de la carpeta en turno
                    if (Directory.Exists(path))
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("La carpeta ya existe.");
                        Console.ReadKey();
                        return;
                    }
                    DirectoryInfo di = Directory.CreateDirectory(path);
                    Console.WriteLine("La carpeta fue creada exitosamente. {0}", Directory.GetCreationTime(path));
                    GetChildrenFolders("sdfgfsdfgg", Convert.ToInt32(row["E_Element_ID"]), conn);

                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Error fatal de la muerte" + ex);
                    Console.ReadKey();
                }
            }

        }

    }

    private static void GetChildrenFolders(string path, int id_parent, SqlConnection conn)
    {
        var cmd = new SqlCommand()
        {
            Connection = conn,
            CommandText = "SELECT * FROM Elements WHERE P_Profile_ID = 2 AND E_Parent_ID =" + id_parent,
            CommandTimeout = 10000
        };

        var sqlDa = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
        var data = new DataTable();
        sqlDa.Fill(data);
        foreach (DataRow row in data.Rows)
        {
            // Tratamiento de subcarpeta
        }
    }
```

Comment: Muchas gracias por tu respuesta, ya le he mandado la conexión, pero ahora me dice que 
**Ya hay un DataReader abierto asociado a este Command, debe cerrarlo primero**.  ¿Cómo puedo solucionar eso? De antemano gracias.

Comment: He ampliado la respuesta. En este caso en el que vas a hacer consultas recursivas te recomendaría utilizar DataAdapters para recuperar la información en DataTables (también podrías pasar la información a listas genéricas o algún otro tipo de colección para mejorar el pobre rendimiento de los DataTables) y así evitar mantener DataReaders abiertos

Comment: Gracias, lo probare y les comento como me fue.

Comment: Me ha funcionado perfecto muchas gracias por la ayuda.